# How to update stock quantity in database by selling item?

Tags: java, sql, database

I have two tables `Items` and `Transactions` in sql database I want to process sale i.e whenever an item gets sold the number of items sold gets subtracted from the total quantity of stock from table `Items` and the transaction detail inserted into `Transaction` table.

**Right now i am using these queries to to get items detail from items table and insert into Transaction table but I am unable to reduce the stock on each item sold.**

```
String query = "Select item_code,item_name, item_price,stock From Items  where Item_name=?";
String query = "Insert into Transactions(transaction_code, transaction_date, item_code, item_name, quantity, item_price, total) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ;";
```

Comment: You have to update your Item table with stock under single transaction scope which insert to transaction table as well as update the item table at same time.

Comment: But how sir is there any way to update items table with stock just by minus the quantity sold from the whole stock in items?

Comment: You should really consider to try something by yourself before posting it here on StackOverflow. [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: I understand Sir, I stuck here for last two day, but if you can help me out it that would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trigger query , i think this article can help you [https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDEV/calling-Java-from-database-triggers.htm](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDEV/calling-Java-from-database-triggers.htm#JJDEV13286)